# Unable to access Mongo Db in router folder

Tags: mongodb

Iam getting stated with meteor.whenever i want to access the collection in the place " collection.js " which is placed in the LIB folder(lib is placed outside of both client and server folder).

It was returning an empty array ([]) .I wrote a query " Console.log(menuDetails.find().fetch()); " in collections.js but an empty array is displayed in console. 
     but when i use "menuDetails.find().fetch()" in console it was returning an array of elements.
     Auto-publish and insecure packages are not removed.

Please help. Thank you..!

Comment: can you show how did you defined db in app.js or server,js?

Comment: menuDetails = new Mongo.Collection("menuDetails");                                                         i defined it in "lib--> Collections.js "